# How to print a Elisp form with a specific prefix string on each line?

Tags: pretty-print

I'd like to pretty-print an Elisp form with some arbitrary prefix string inserted at the beginning of each output line.

For example, given the following variable:

```lisp
(setq var '((abc . 11)
            (def . 22)
            (ghi . 33)))
```

I'd like something like `(pp-with-prefix var " ---> ")` (or something like it) to be able to add the `" ---> "` prefix string (or anything) so I could get something like the following printed:

```lisp
 ---> ((abc . 11)
 --->  (def . 22)
 --->  (ghi . 33))
```

instead of what `(pp var)` would normally print:

```lisp
((abc . 11)
 (def . 22)
 (ghi . 33))
```

Comment: Use `pp-to-string` to produce the string and then do string manipulation to do anything you want. The `s` string library will probably be useful. See https://github.com/magnar4s/s.el

Comment: @NickD That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks.  Please add this as the answer and I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that `pp` does is call `pp-to-string` on the object and then it calls `princ` to print the string. So you can use `pp-to-string` in your own function and then manipulate the resulting string any way you want, before printing it out.

The `s` string library might be useful for such manipulation. See https://github.com/magnars/s.el